# Some applications do not have proper graphics after sleep in ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, 20.10

Programs such as chrome, opera, etc. are displayed after the computer wakes up, as shown below, and do not work properly, although they must be closed and opened once to work.
Sometimes a completely black screen is displayed and sometimes pages like the image are displayed.
please help.
[image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jhiE.png)
[image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diM5P.png)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to upgrade video driver, if you have Nvidia video card then try this instruction if not find your video graphic card chipset and google it for driver update

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-linux

Comment: I updated the nvidia graphics card and the update path is as follows.
sortware & updates -> additional drivers.
or
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall.